# Syntax errors with parsing f-strings in PyDev Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.6, pydev, f-string

I've a python project using PyDev in Eclipse. For sample code like below,

```
var = 'element'
width = 11
print(f'{var:>{width}}')
```

the code is executed printing the desired output `element` with right alignment and no errors.

However, PyDev parses this code raising error at `>` character and an error message `SyntaxError: Unbalanced '{'`. But PyDev does support double braces in f-strings since release 6.3.1 ([#PyDev-884](http://www.pydev.org/history_pydev.html)). If I remove this `>` character, the string is printed 'left-aligned' (which I don't want) and PyDev doesn't raise any error. This confirms PyDev does support double braces, but the error message is incorrect.

On the other hand, [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#differences-between-f-string-and-str-format-expressions) for f-strings doesn't mention anything about alignment using f-strings. Is alignment part of the f-string syntax? If it is why is it not mentioned in PEP guide, and why does PyDev parser raise an error?

1. Python: 3.6.3
2. PyDev: 6.3.3
3. Eclipse: Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)

Thanks!

Comment: Alignment is a valid way of using f-strings.  They use the same [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) that `str.format` does, which include the alignment syntax.  Your IDE is complaining because usually `}}` is how you escape a `}` in an f-string.  It's counting two opening expressions, but no closing ones because it thinks `}}` is a literal `}` character.  I'm a little surprised this works actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue in PyDev (unfortunately https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ does not provide a grammar for f-strings and is very light on how the expected parsing should take place -- I'll update PyDev to cover for the provided example).

Comment: Thanks Fabio. Appreciate it!

Comment: Just released PyDev 6.4.1. Can you check if it's fixed for you?

Comment: The errors at the f-string line have disappeared. However, there are still 'Unused variable' warnings at the lines where variables used in the inner braces of the f-string are defined.

Comment: Yeap... I had tested that snippet in the global scope before, so, the unused variable warning wasn't appearing, but you're right, there's still an issue there. Will take a look at it for 6.4.2.

Comment: Thanks, Fabio for the update in 6.4.2. I've noticed a new `SyntaxError` popped up at the decimal while parsing f-strings of kind `f'{val:{width}.{precision}f}'`. Further the variable inside the braces is highlighted with shift towards left by one character as `{precision`}

Comment: Just fixed that error in https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/090d95d89ce244f00bc8f635087725ae5c38b341 (for PyDev 6.4.4).

Comment: @Fabio: Still not working: logger.info(f'Request received: {data}') >> syntax error. eclipse pydev plugin 7.3.0 Encountered "\'Request received: {data}\'" Was expecting one of:     "(" ...     ")" 
 ...     "[" ...     "," ...     "." ...     "+" ...     "-" ...     "*" ...     "/" ...     "//" ...     "<<" ...     ">>" ...     "%" ...     "^" ...     "|" ... >>> etc.

Comment: @Sujith R Kumar it does work for me (maybe you have set the project to use a different grammar in the grammar properties?) -- see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for the place to configure that.

Comment: As suggestd, I updated Project -> Properties -> PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar -> Grammar Version. Then, once I made a modification in the file, all the warnings and errors went away.